# JTable en java me repite una fila que ya existe

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Muy buenas a todos, tengo problemas con un algoritmo en java que me esta repitiendo filas que ya existen, dare mi explicacion

tengo el siguiente metodo al cual le envio un codigo de barras por medio de un jtextfield y lo que me tiene que retornar es el nombre de algun producto que tengo agregado en una base de datos en mysql

```
public String BuscarProducto(String codigo){
    String query = "SELECT modelo FROM `productos` WHERE codigo_barras = '"+codigo+"'";
    String modeloObtenido = "";
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
        
        while (rs.next()) {                
            modeloObtenido = rs.getNString("modelo");
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR CONSULTAS PRODUCTOS 390990: " + ex);
    }
    return modeloObtenido;
}
```

hasta aqui todo bien, la conexion se hace correctamente y si me devuelve el modelo obtenido, en este caso si ingreso el codigo 1010 me devuelve el nombre "pizza"

el problema esta cuando quiero pasar este resultado a un jtable, mi tabla es la siguiente

ejemplo de jtable*

| modelo | piezas en salida |
| --- | --- |

lo que quiero hacer es poner el resultado obtenido que en este caso es pizza en modelo y poner en la siguiente columna 1

de esta forma

| modelo | piezas en salida |
| --- | --- |
| pizza | 1 |

piezas en salida quiere decir que va a salir solo 1 producto

el asunto es que quiero que cuando vuelvan a ingresar el codigo pizza, en la columna **piezas en salida** se me actualice a 2, es decir que van a salir 2 pizzas y si lo vuelven a poner que sean 3  y asi sucesivamente

hasta aqui todo bien, logre hacer esto, pero cuando quiero ingresar otro codigo, por ejemplo **1110 -> agua** tambien me lo ingresa a la tabla y me lo pone en 1, dejandolo asi

| modelo | piezas en salida |
| --- | --- |
| pizza | 2 |
| agua | 1 |

pero si vuelvo a ingresar ese mismo codigo del **agua** me lo ingresando, y el primer registro llamado agua me lo pone 2, si, pero despues me ingresa ese registro dejandolo asi

| modelo | piezas en salida |
| --- | --- |
| pizza | 2 |
| agua | 2 |
| agua | 1 |

y despues asi

| modelo | piezas en salida |
| --- | --- |
| pizza | 2 |
| agua | 3 |
| agua | 2 |
| agua | 1 |

no se como resolver este algoritmo, ya me llevo vario rato pensando como resolverlo

```
    public void InsertarEnTablaEmbarque(){
    String codigo = vista.jTextField_codigoEmbarque.getText(); //aqui obtengo el codigo 
    tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) vista.jTable_embarque.getModel(); 
    Integer valorActual = 0;
    int tamanotabla = tmodel.getRowCount();
    String modeloSala = modelo.BuscarProducto(codigo); //aqui me devuelve el nombre del producto
    
    if (tamanotabla == 0) { //aqui lo que quiero hacer es que si no tiene registros la jtable que se inserte el primer registro nada mas
        
        tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {modeloSala, 1});
    } else { //cuando ya no se cumple, es decir que la tabla ya tiene tama;o hacer validaciones
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanotabla; i++) { //recorro la tabla
            
            if (tmodel.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(modeloSala)) { //si lo que hay en un registro es iugual a lo que me esta llegando, quiero actualizar la columna piezas en salida y sumarle 1
                
                valorActual = (Integer) tmodel.getValueAt(i, 1);
                tmodel.setValueAt((valorActual + 1), i, 1);
            
            } else { //y en caso de que sea un nuevo registro, es decir que no este en la tabla quiero que se inserte nada mas
                tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {modeloSala, 1});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y por ultimo ingreso una fotografia del problema que me esta pasando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanotabla; i++) { //recorro la tabla
        
        if (tmodel.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(modeloSala)) { //si lo que hay en un registro es iugual a lo que me esta llegando, quiero actualizar la columna piezas en salida y sumarle 1
            
            valorActual = (Integer) tmodel.getValueAt(i, 1);
            tmodel.setValueAt((valorActual + 1), i, 1);
        
        } else { //y en caso de que sea un nuevo registro, es decir que no este en la tabla quiero que se inserte nada mas
            tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {modeloSala, 1});
        }
    }
```

Tienes un problema de concepto. Aquí recorres la tabla, y, **en cada iteración añades un elemento si no te coincide en esa iteración**.

Es decir, cuando descubres que el primer elemento es *pizza* y no *agua* añades el elemento *agua*, sin comprobar si *agua* está en la lista.

Dentro del `for` solo sabes si el elemento actual es o no es el que buscas. Para saber que el elemento buscado está en la lista, tiene que ser que nunca aparece.

Lo que tienes que hacer es:

- Si encuentras el elemento, incrementas el contador (o haces lo que tengas que hacer), y marcas de alguna forma(por ejemplo una variable *boolean*) que lo has encontrado.
- **Una vez que has salido del bucle**, si no está marcado que has encontrado el elemento, eso significa que no es ninguno de los elementos. Entonces lo añades a la lista.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, asi era, estuve revisando con el debug el comportamiento de mi metodo y estaba pasando justo como lo describes, ya pude soliucionarlo!

Answer (score 0):

gracias [@sjuan76](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/14311/sjuan76) pude resolverlo! era un problema de lógica muchas gracias, pongo el código que realice.

```
    public void InsertarEnTablaEmbarque(){
String codigo = vista.jTextField_codigoEmbarque.getText(); //aqui obtengo el codigo 
tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) vista.jTable_embarque.getModel(); 
Integer valorActual = 0;
int tamanotabla = tmodel.getRowCount();
String modeloSala = modelo.BuscarProducto(codigo); //aqui me devuelve el nombre del producto
boolean encontrado = false;

if (tamanotabla == 0) { //aqui lo que quiero hacer es que si no tiene registros la jtable que se inserte el primer registro nada mas
    
    tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {modeloSala, 1});
} else { //cuando ya no se cumple, es decir que la tabla ya tiene tama;o hacer validaciones
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanotabla; i++) { //recorro la tabla
        
        if (tmodel.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(modeloSala)) { //si lo que hay en un registro es iugual a lo que me esta llegando, quiero actualizar la columna piezas en salida y sumarle 1
            
            valorActual = (Integer) tmodel.getValueAt(i, 1);
            tmodel.setValueAt((valorActual + 1), i, 1);
            encontrado = true;
            if (encontrado) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (encontrado == false) {
        tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {modeloSala, 1});
    }
}
```

}